# Parsley.js not working on multi-page form, using data-parsley-group

Tags: parsley.js

I'm running into problems trying to validate a multipage form using Parsley.  My client is using a multipage jquery plugin that retrieves all the fieldsets within the form, and displays the questions in each fieldset, step by step. It also has a built-in validation function that I can customize, which is called each time the user clicks the button to get to the next step.

I've grouped my checkboxes together with data-parsley-group='fieldset1', and on the next page, data-parsley-group='fieldset2', etc etc.  Then, from within the built-in validation function of my multipage plugin, I'm calling:

```
jQuery.fn.validatePage = function(page) {
    return $(this).parsley().validate('fieldset' + page);
}
```

(page is an incrementor, starting at 1).  If jQuery.fn.validatePage returns true, the multipage jquery plugin increments page and moves on to display the next step.

Parsley validation works exactly as expected on the first page. However, once validation returns true from page 1, and then the second page is displayed, parsley validate always returns true, even if required fields are left empty.  It's almost as if I need to 'reset' the parsley validation, but since I am validating on a specific data-parsley-group, this shouldn't be necessary.  Here is the HTML markup (bear with me on the code, tried to clean it up a bit but it is being created dynamically through our CMS for now:

```
<form id="survey-form" method="post" data-parsley-validate="data-parsley-validate" data-parsley-errors-container="#survey-form .error-container" class="js_multipage-form">
<div class="error-container"></div>
<fieldset>
    <div class="title section">
        Question 1
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox section">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectiongroup" value="Item 1" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-mincheck="1" data-parsley-trigger="ifChanged" data-parsley-group="fieldset1" class="form_field form_field_checkbox"/>&nbsp;Item 1
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectiongroup" value="Item 2" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-mincheck="1" data-parsley-trigger="ifChanged" data-parsley-group="fieldset1" class="form_field form_field_checkbox"/>&nbsp;Item 2
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectiongroup" value="Item 3" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-mincheck="1" data-parsley-trigger="ifChanged" data-parsley-group="fieldset1" class="form_field form_field_checkbox"/>&nbsp;Item 3
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectiongroup" value="Item 4" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-mincheck="1" data-parsley-trigger="ifChanged" data-parsley-group="fieldset1" class="form_field form_field_checkbox"/>&nbsp;Item 4
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectiongroup" value="Item 5" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-mincheck="1" data-parsley-trigger="ifChanged" data-parsley-group="fieldset1" class="form_field form_field_checkbox"/>&nbsp;Item 5
    </div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset>
    <div class="title section">
        Question 2
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox section">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectiongroup" value="Item 1" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-mincheck="1" data-parsley-trigger="ifChanged" data-parsley-group="fieldset2" class="form_field form_field_checkbox"/>&nbsp;Item 1
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectiongroup" value="Item 2" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-mincheck="1" data-parsley-trigger="ifChanged" data-parsley-group="fieldset2" class="form_field form_field_checkbox"/>&nbsp;Item 2
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectiongroup" value="Item 3" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-mincheck="1" data-parsley-trigger="ifChanged" data-parsley-group="fieldset2" class="form_field form_field_checkbox"/>&nbsp;Item 3
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectiongroup" value="Item 4" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-mincheck="1" data-parsley-trigger="ifChanged" data-parsley-group="fieldset2" class="form_field form_field_checkbox"/>&nbsp;Item 4
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I've been trying for hours to get this to work as expected, but to no avail.  Is there another technique that would be worth looking into?  I saw that Parsley 1.0 had a different multipage solution where it was not running validation on the :hidden elements.  I tried using the exclude option to hide these, but that didn't work with this multipage plugin, either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry if this code is so verbose, I tried including all possibly relevant code I could.

Comment: I am also struggling with the same problem and I was not getting up any solution, if you will bring any solution please post here

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a json object to the validate funciton

```
jQuery.fn.validatePage = function(page) {
    return $(this).parsley().validate({group:'fieldset' + page});
}
```

See example at http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/multisteps.html